# how to work with rails activerecord sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have login page... (First of all, I using rails 2.3.11 and using MYSQL)

and admin page (you can access there using password and login).

How active record session works?

1) in `config/environment.rb` (or in `config/initializers.rb` ?) i should write:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

2) create sessions table with id, session_id, data, created_at, updated_at fields (created already)

and what else? How I can work with them?

Now i write this way: `session[:user].is_admin` .. And how i can write this using activerecord sessions?

Thank you for help. Im newbie in this:(

Answer (score 0):

Try watching the [**Railscasts** on sessions](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=session) They may help you with finer points about sessions in general.